# Find axis of rotation given rotation angle

Tags: math, opencv

I have a plane which is rotated 90 degrees around an unknown axis. I know a point and normal for the plane before and after the rotation. How can I find the axis of rotation?

I've done a sketch to illustrate - it's 2D but the problem is actually 3D. [image: Terribly drawn sketch of the problem.]

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you have? How do you describe a plane? How do you define the translation vector?

Comment: The problem isn't really implementation-specific, I just want the general maths behind the problem. That said, assume the plane is defined as a point and normal. Opencv gives the rotation and translation matrices needed to transform the plane from the origin to wherever. All I meant to say by mentioning those was that I know the position and rotation of each plane.

Answer (score 1):

I worked it out with some help from @davin.

Use the cross product to find the direction of the rotation axis. The two known points on the planes and the unknown point on the rotation axis make an isosceles triangle, so simple geometry finds the unknown point.

Answer (score 0):

The *axis of rotation* is an eigenvector of the rotation matrix. Moreover, it has eigenvalue 1. Every rotation matrix has such an eigenvector. Then just apply the translation to the eigenvector (presuming you're rotating and then translating) to get the final axis of rotation.

Mathematically, you need to solve `Rv = v`, which is equivalent to finding the nullspace of `R-I`.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but which rotation matrix do I derive the eigenvector from?

Comment: @user754677, I thought you have the rotation matrix. If not you can derive it, although there's an easier way: Given the two normals, before and after the rotation, the axis of rotation is simply the vector that is normal to both those vectors, i.e. the cross-product of those two vectors!

Comment: Thanks, that gets me a bit closer. Using the cross product gives the direction of the axis, but not the position. A worked example would be helpful, use the picture I made as an example. Say the left plane is at (-1,3,0) with normal (1,1,0) and the right is at (3,3,0) with (-1,1,0). The axis of rotation is in the direction (0,0,1), but how do I work out its position? It should be (1,5,whatever).